# Which file is used to define the list of services available in an application on Adobe commerce cloud?

Tags: magento2.4, magento-cloud

Was going through official Magento Certification AD0-E717 mockup test, have a doubt on one of the answer -

I selected option D but it's showing Answer A -

[image]

Here it's clearly saying *services.yaml* for the same -

[https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-cloud-service/user-guide/configure/service/services-yaml.html#:~:text=The%20services.,Redis%2C%20and%20Elasticsearch%20or%20OpenSearch](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-cloud-service/user-guide/configure/service/services-yaml.html#:%7E:text=The%20services.,Redis%2C%20and%20Elasticsearch%20or%20OpenSearch).

Can anyone please confirm the best answer here, it's confusing as services also uses file *.magento.app.yaml*

Answer (score 2):

Yes, answer A is right because they ask to list of services available in an **application** on adobe commerce cloud please read question again.

Comment: Thanks for response, I have a query - 

How .magento/services.yaml is different than that we define into .magento.app.yaml ?

Comment: Oh, I understood now - 

The services.yaml file defines the services supported and used by Adobe Commerce on cloud infrastructure while .magento.app.yaml defines services available in an application.

Comment: @WakarAhamad - Yes, exactly.